# DateTime wrong result (potential bug?)

Tags: php, datetime

for verification as a bug, can someone test this with his php:

```
$timeZone = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin');
$startDate = new DateTime('first day this month 00:00:00', $timeZone);
echo $startDate->format('d.m.Y');
```

Result:

```
02.02.2013
```

I've tested it with php 5.2 and PHP 5.3, with same result....

As a "resolution", what's the best alternate way to do this?

```
$timeZone = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin');
$startDateAlt = new DateTime('now', $timeZone);
$startDateAlt->setTimestamp(mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m") , 1, date("Y")));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You omitted the `of`, so it parses it as something else:

```
$timeZone = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin');
$startDate = new DateTime('first day of this month 00:00:00', $timeZone);
echo $startDate->format('d.m.Y');
```

returns

```
01.02.2013
```

If for some reason this doesn't work (old php version it seems from your comment), you can try this? Bit of a hack maybe...

```
$startDate = new DateTime();
$days = $startDate->format('d');
$days = $days - 1;
$startDate->modify("-{$day} days");
$startDate->setTime(0,0,0);
echo $startDate->format('d.m.Y');
```

Comment: edit:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php#104214

*of* is not possible, in case of thats a 5.3 feature and the server supports 5.2

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that link, but if you look up in that same page you see the "first day of" examples. clearly stating "of". In other news, I'll add another method...

Comment: i've used mktime instead... maybe its not the best practice, but it works well on php 5.2:

    date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m") , 1, date("Y")));
    date('Y-m-d 23:59:59', mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m") + 1, 0, date("Y") + 2))

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing an *of* in `first day this month`. Try:

```
$timeZone = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin');
$startDate = new DateTime('first day of this month 00:00:00', $timeZone);
echo $startDate->format('r') . PHP_EOL;
```